# vertically aligning text in HTML select element cross browsers

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML select element with the following CSS:

```
.MySelect{
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 4px;
    background: white;
    width:180px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px lightgray;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 26px;
    line-height: 26px;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
    font-size: 13px;
    margin:20px 20px;}
```

The problem is that the text is not vertically aligned in Firefox even thought it is in Chrome. **See the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rkpLB/7/) here for demo.**

How do I make the text vertically aligned across all browsers?

*Edit: I tried modifying the padding before asking this question and that doesn't work.*

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The added padding helps in FFox and chrome doesn't seem to mind.

```
.MySelect{
        padding: 2px 0px 2px 4px;
        background: white;
        width:180px;
        border: 2px solid red;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px lightgray;
        border-radius: 5px;
        font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
        font-size: 13px;
        margin:20px 20px;
}
```

Comment: That's what initially tried too; working with the padding. The problem is that it makes the text aligned in Firefox but now look at the result in Chrome!

Comment: It looks the same on Chrome OS X

Comment: Looks the same with `2px` as with `0px` to me. Chrome 23 (release)

Comment: No way it looks the same!! Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/rkpLB/7/ It's clearly different!!! I tried the padding route and it doesn't work.

Comment: Well look here: http://snag.gy/Wbd1k.jpg Clearly not a cross browser solution to adjust paddings

Comment: Yeah, obviosly it looks different on Windows. I'm using Chrome on OSX and it looks good to me, that's all the feedback I can give you. It looks fine on Safari too. Maybe try removing the height property and playing around with padding, that works on OSX too.

Comment: Well the idea of removing the height and line-height and using just the padding is the answer! Now it's cross-browser the same; thanks. I edited your answer and removed the height and padding.

Answer (score 2):

If you want total control, I would suggest making your input have a "-webkit-appearance:none;"

Here is the CSS to recreate the appearance:

```
.MySelect {
width: 180px;
height: 26px;
padding:0px 0px 0px 4px;
border: 2px solid red;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px lightgray;
border-radius: 5px;
font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
font-size: 13px;
-webkit-appearance: none;
background: #E7E7E7;
background: url("http://www.412webdesigns.com/upload/arrows.png") no-repeat right, -moz-linear-gradient(top, #E7E7E7 0%, #FEFEFE 100%);
background: url("http://www.412webdesigns.com/upload/arrows.png") no-repeat right, -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#E7E7E7), color-stop(100%,#FEFEFE));
background: url("http://www.412webdesigns.com/upload/arrows.png") no-repeat right, -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #E7E7E7 0%,#FEFEFE 100%);
background: url("http://www.412webdesigns.com/upload/arrows.png") no-repeat right, -o-linear-gradient(top, #E7E7E7 0%,#FEFEFE 100%);
background: url("http://www.412webdesigns.com/upload/arrows.png") no-repeat right, -ms-linear-gradient(top, #E7E7E7 0%,#FEFEFE 100%);
background: url("http://www.412webdesigns.com/upload/arrows.png") no-repeat right, linear-gradient(to bottom, #E7E7E7 0%,#FEFEFE 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e7e7e7', endColorstr='#fefefe',GradientType=0 );
}
```

And then if that one pixel is bothering you in FireFox, Use something like this:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
.MySelect {
    padding:1px 0px 0px 4px;
}
}
```

With webkit appearance, you can make it look like whatever you want in any browser.

EDIT:  Make sure you DOWNLOAD the arrows.png from my site and then use it locally, I will only have it there for a little while.

Comment: Upvoted cause it works but it looks really complex to me. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah the confusing part is really the gradients. Other than that its pretty Mich the same